# Where can I find the soundtracks to the Left 4 Dead games?

Tags: left-4-dead-series

Where can I find Left 4 Dead and Left 4 Dead 2 soundtracks?

Do they officially exist?

Comment: I think [this track](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vJ2Kn74qBpU) is my favourite one. Steady intro leading into some very skilled vocal work, then building into a massive climax at the end that will have you absolutely reeling.

Comment: @Sadly Not - That was one of the most exquisite pieces of art I've ever heard! Thank you, truly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no official soundtrack, as far as I know, but you could try the [Left 4 Dead wikia Soundtrack page](http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/Left_4_Dead_Soundtrack), which has all the different songs from both games arranged in nifty little youtube clips.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity <sub>(and those without good net)</sub>;

You can find them in your game directory, most of the actual music (you can find all the other scores and sound bytes in these folders) resides in;

```
left4dead2\sound\music\cpmusic
left4dead2\sound\music\l4d2
```

These are subdirectories of your game directory which would normally be located at;

```
%programfiles%\Steam\steamapps\common\left 4 dead 2
```

<sub>(the duplication of the `L4D` phrase is no accident)</sub>

Comment: upvote for both of you (question and answer), but I ended up finding them on my own. Added different solution as addendum